# How to add a new column in an SQL select query with a specific type?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create an empty column with a specific type in a select query.

This is how I can do it without specifying the type:

```
Select *, Null as new_empty_colum from my_table;
```

In this examples, it creates it of type `string`.

My question is how can I specify the type of `new_empty_colum` and why does it make it as `string` when I don't specify a type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untyped values default to `text`, if you want to force a specific type, you have to cast the `null` value:

```
select *, cast(null as numeric) as new_empty_column
from my_table
```